# If A and B are both odd-square matrices, such that AB= -BA & A is invertible, then B is not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

If $A$ and $B$ are both odd-square matrices, such that $AB= -BA$ & $A$ is invertible, then $B$ is not invertible?

Given $A$ , $B$ $\in$ $M_{n\times n}(R)$ such that

$AB= -BA$ and

$ A$ is invertible and

$n$ is an odd number,

then how can I prove that $B$ is **not** invertible?

Comment: $\det(AB)=\det(-BA)\implies ?$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since,
$$AB = -BA$$
$$\therefore \det(AB) = \det(-BA)$$
Also since,
$$\det(kA) = k^n\det(A)$$
and $n$ is given to be odd here, therefore,
$$\det(-BA) = (-1)^n\det(BA) = -\det(BA)$$

$$\therefore \det(A)\det(B) = -\det(B)\det(A)$$
$$\therefore \det(A)\det(B) + \det(B)\det(A) = 0$$
$$\therefore 2\det(A)\det(B) = 0$$
As $A$ is invertible hence $\det(A) \neq 0$, hence the only possibility now is,
$$\det(B) = 0$$
Hence proved that $B$ is not invertible since it's determinant is **zero**.

Comment: Nice proof.  We need $2\neq 0$ for this to work.  If $R$ means $\mathbb{R}$, then we're all set; if it is an arbitrary ring then we're in trouble.  Why is $n$ odd?

Comment: It is worth expanding on where the third line comes from.  $\det(kA)=k^n\det(A)$, and because $n$ is odd by assumption, $(-1)^n=-1$.  So we are explicitly making use of that fact that n is odd, even though the proof does not make it clear.

Comment: @Aaron : Thanks for pointing it out, I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 3):

$\det(AB)=\det(-BA)$ then $\det(A)\det(B)=(-1)^n\det(B)\det(A)$.

because of $n$ is odd we have $(-1)^n=-1$ so $\det(A)\det(B)=-\det(B)\det(A)$.

In addition we have $\det(A)$ is non zero and we can omit it from the equation then we have $\det(B)=-\det(B)$ and so $2\det(B)=0$ and it means $B$ is not invertible.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. While the mathematical content of your answer is perfectly fine, please try to format your next answers with Mathjax.

Comment: Thank you so much for your favor. You right and in the next answers I will use Mathjax Format.